# Can't shutdown Windows 8 from Linux

Tags: windows-8, samba, remote, remote-shutdown

I'm having trouble setting up a shutdown over LAN from a raspberry pi to a windows 8.1 PC. I get all sort of different errors. I'm logged with the Administrator account and I've set up a password (on the Windows PC). If I try from the RaspberryPi:

```
net rpc shutdown -I 192.168.1.100 -U Administrator
```

I get:

```
Enter Administrator's password:
Could not connect to server 192.168.1.100
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Could not connect to server 192.168.1.100
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Even though the password is correct. If I try to include the workgroup, the message is more or less the same, except for the first part that doesn't say logon failure and instead says:

```
Could not connect to server 192.168.1.100
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

I tried turning off the Windows Firewall and didn't help. Also tried entering gibberish into the password field and got the same message as before (logon failure twice).

Any ideas what I'm missing here? I looked around in google for a bit but most solutions where for XP machines, and asked to turn off simple file sharing (which AFAIK is no longer present in W8) and to turn on echo requests and printer and file sharing, which I did.

Comment: Does the user `Administrator` even exist?

Comment: It does apparently, here's the screenshot http://postimg.org/image/bbuh2b4eb/ I think it's the superuser equivalent in windows 8.

Comment: Alright; I assume you have verified that you are able to log into the account you trying to use to shutdown the target computer with on the computer itself?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact it's my personal computer. I'm writing from it right now